# Binding CollectionView to an ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple ember-data model called a Task.  When I route to `/tasks`, I can iterate over each task to create a list of all the tasks via my TasksController, template, and autogenerated view:

```
{{#each task in filteredContent}}
  {{ partial "taskItem" }}
{{/each}}
```

`filteredContent` is a property watching the content and a filter criteria to provide a subset of `App.Task.find()`.

This works well, but now I'd like to add more functionality to my tasks list, namely drag-and-drop sorting via jQuery's sortable plugin.  Since I'd like to encapsulate the logic for displaying the tasks, I created a TasksListController:

```
App.TasksListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend {
  needs: ['tasks']
  contentBinding: 'controllers.tasks.filteredContent'
}
```

a TasksListView:

```
App.TasksListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend {
  tagName: 'ul'
  classNames: ['tasks-list']
  itemViewClass: App.TasksListItemView

  didInsertElement: ->
    this._super();
    this.$().sortable().disableSelection();
}
```

and a TasksListItemView:

```
App.TasksListItemView = Ember.View.extend {
  templateName: 'tasks-list-item'
  classNames: ['task-item']
}
```

If I insert `console.log this.get 'controller.firstObject'` in the `didInsertElement` method, the output is correct, but `{{render tasks-list}}` in the Tasks template (operating under the TasksController if I understand things correctly) always seems like there is no content.  I've come across a few examples using CollectionView, but they seem to be pre-RC1, and suggest doing something like `{{view 'App.TasksListView' contentBinding=filteredContent'}}` (which doesn't seem to work either).

In this situation, is the `render` or `view` helper the appropriate way to go?  Is this the right way to approach this problem, or is there a better Ember pattern to follow?

I am using Ember.js RC2 and ember-data DS.FixtureAdapter (revision 12).  A simplified fiddle is available at http://jsfiddle.net/superlou/sUUXj/.

Comment: Does {{render tasksList}} behave similarly?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get to the computer with the full code right now, but I created a [simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superlou/sUUXj/) that seems to have the same result. In the fiddle, I call the controller simply List, to avoid any ambiguity over tasks-list, "TasksList", tasks_list, etc.

Comment: {{render tasksList}} does behave similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out to be relatively straightforward.  The CollectionView does not automatically inherit content from the controller, so the view must be modified to include:

```
App.TasksListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend {
    contentBinding: 'controller'
    ...
```

The content can then be accessed in the template like so:

```
{{#linkTo task view.content}}
    {{#with view.content}}
        <div class="task-item">
            {{name}}
        </div>
    {{/with}}
{{/linkTo}}
```

Many thanks to panoptic at [Ember Discuss](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/binding-collectionview-to-an-arraycontroller/940/6).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jsbin to show how you can implement that easily.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yideji/2/edit

```
App.TasksListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  itemViewClass: App.TasksListItemView,

  // A `CollectionView` expects its data in the `content`
  // property. But the route will set the `controller` on the view, not the `content`.
  // Using bindings allows to make that transparent to the developer.
  contentBinding: 'controller'
});
```

The nice thing you can add is in your `item` view:

```
App. TasksListItemView = Ember.View.extend({      
  // A view applys its `context` to the template. The `context` is usually its `controller`.
  // In the case of an item of a `CollectionView`, `context` isn't set, but `content` is.
  // So we just bind `context` to `content` so we don't have to write `view.content.myValue`
  // but `myValue` in the template
  contextBinding: 'content'
})
```

Adding this will allow you to simplify your template:

```
{{#linkTo task this}}
    <div class="task-item">
        {{name}}
    </div>
{{/linkTo}}
```